# VBA: Conver Text -> Number multiplying by 1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table linked to a SQL database that I use to create some reports. The problem is that the numbers come as text and I have to convert them to numbers everytime,
I've wrote a macro to create the report but I'm having trouble to convert the numbers. I tried to multiply the whole table by one (the table lose the link but it's not an issue, since I'll just copy the infos to another workbook and them close the table w/o saving) and it worked when I did it manualy, but when I do it via macro it won't work. I can see it multiplying by 1 but the numbers are still texts.

Since my table is huge, trying to convert each cell is not an options sice it'd take forever to run each cell and use the CStr function.

My code:

```
Range("B2").Copy
Range("A4", Range("AC4").End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your current code................

Comment: Hey, I've edit my question so now it has the code!

Comment: consider changing the format of cells from Text to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

`xlDown` can be highly unpredictive. Don't use that. In fact find the last row and then create your range and then use that for your operations.

Also just changing the format will not convert those to number. You will have to replicate the `F2-Enter` behavior.

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range, acell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("AC" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set Rng = .Range("A4:AC" & lRow)

        .Range("B2").Copy

        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlMultiply, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Rng.NumberFormat = "0" ' OR "0.00" as applicable

        For Each acell In Rng
            acell.Formula = acell.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: + Perfect explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and heads up about the xldown.
It worked for most of my data, except for one columns (I have numbers like this: ,4551 3164.1311). I just figured out the problem. Here we use the comma (,) for decimals and period (.) for thousands, and VBA uses period for decimals and comma for thousands, so after mutiplying ,45 it's still ,45 and 6,682615 become 6682615. I'd have to change all the commas for dots. 
One question about your code why do you do the `acell.Formula = acell.Value`
I have 200k rows, so this will take forever to run each cell, wouldn't only muplying be enought?

Comment: @FabioRebelo: Strange, I didn't get an alert for that you replied. We do that because we are trying to replicate the `F2-Enter` behavior.

Comment: Ahh that's a really useful tip! I've always wondered how to do that!
Thank you

Comment: Yes, I used your code for most my table, except for the "problematic column" with the data like ,46484.
To fix it I ran a code like this
`Set rng = Range("S4", Range("S4").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    cell.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, ",", ".")
Next`

Comment: @FabioRebelo don't you first have to remove the `.` (which are your thousands markers) before substituting a `,`->`.`?

Comment: @Floris, yeah you're right, I'd have to do that but my data doesnt come with ".", so it's like 1564,45, but sure enough I'd have to do something like:
`WorksheetFunction.Substitute(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, ".", ""), ",", ".")`

Comment: I was referring to your comment above "Here we use the comma (,) for decimals and period (.) for thousands". I assumed this meant your numbers had periods in them. But I see now they don't _have_ to. Thanks for the clarification.