# Adding text to a cell in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working with SQL and Excel Macros, but I don't know how to add text to a cell.

I wish to add the text `"01/01/13 00:00"` to cell `A1`. I can't just write it in the cell because the macro clears the contents of the sheet first and adds the information afterwards.

How do I do that in VBA?

Comment: locate the line that clears the contents and modify it. or use `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"` and then `Range("A1") = "01/01/13 00:00"`

Comment: @mehow that's better than both answers; one of them is mine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Range("$A$1").Value = "'01/01/13 00:00"` will do it.

Note the single quote; this will defeat automatic conversion to a number type. But is that what you *really* want? An alternative would be to format the cell to take a date-time value. Then drop the single quote from the string.

Comment: +1 for great minds thinking alike - but you were a bit faster as I was adding the explanation of the `[A1]` notation.

Comment: Text is fine but thank you I will try both just in case.

Comment: This doesnt work for me.. it works for some cells where i add some numbers, but not for adding text to some.. it is a protected worksheet but i can enter text in the cells manually.. what could be the issue that the macro fails? i just used Range("$D$2").Value = "'test"

Answer (score 11):

You could do

```
[A1].Value = "'O1/01/13 00:00"
```

if you really mean to add it as *text* (note the apostrophe as the first character).

The `[A1].Value` is VBA shorthand for `Range("A1").Value`.

If you want to enter a date, you could instead do (edited order with thanks to @SiddharthRout):

```
[A1].NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm;@"
[A1].Value = DateValue("01/01/2013 00:00")
```

Comment: Text is fine because I'm using this as a template to format the timestamps in the SQL table. Thanks.

Comment: Beware that the apostrophe will be there as a real character. SQL might not like that.

Comment: + 1 to you and @Bathsheba. The only drawback is what you both accepted. i.e apostrophe being treated as a real character.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks. I agree - this is why I gave the alternative (which puts the right text in the right place in the right format without additional characters sneaking in).

Comment: unfortunately the alternative will not work. Let me explain. Try this. Format cell A1 as text manually. and now run your code. You will notice that you do not get the desired result. One should always change the numberformat first :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I did not realize that was the behavior - thanks for the tip I have updated the answer (changed the order of the two statements). Strange - when I do this in the spreadsheet I would ALWAYS enter the value first, then format it. Can you think of a reason why it behaves this way?

Comment: That is because when you input a value in a cell, it inherits the format which already exists in that cell. After that if you format the cell, it may or maynot adapt to the new format. Classic case can be seen in terms of dates which gets stored as text. In such a scenario, you change the number format first and then use `.Formula` instead of `.value` which is nothing but simulation `F2-Enter`. For example see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192371/vba-conver-text-number-multiplying-by-1) post

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `Range` and `Valu`e functions.
`Range` would be the cell where you want the text you want
`Value` would be the text that you want in that Cell

```
Range("A1").Value="whatever text"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the cell property.

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hey, what's up?"
```

Make sure to use a `.` before `Cells(1,1).Value` as in `.Cells(1,1).Value`, if you are using it within `With` function. If you are selecting some sheet.