# Excel VBA - Convert string entered in user form to number

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel user form into which the user enters numbers, when those numbers are entered into the spreadsheet they appear with the notification that this is a number stored as text. =SUM(H6:H13) shows a zero result.
I have tried **NumCrtn = cLng(NumCrtn)** - doesn't change the cell to a number, formula still shows zero.
I have tried **NumCrtn = Val(NumCrtn)** - doesn't change the cell to a number, formula still shows zero.

I have tried copy and paste.special to a value and that doesn't change it to a number either.
Don't know what to do.

Help!

Comment: Change the `NumberFormat` of the `Range` to Numeric and check if it is still showing the message

Comment: Just changing the number format will not work. If your range is `H6:H13` then you have to change the format before you write to the cell. For example

`Range("H6:H13").NumberFormat = "#,##0"` and then `Range("H6").Value = "Something"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA: Conver Text -> Number multiplying by 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192371/vba-conver-text-number-multiplying-by-1)

Comment: I tried that and didn't do anything.

Comment: May I see your excel file?

Comment: Hi Siddarth - didn't see your comment when I said Tried that... Modified the code from the page you referred to and it worked!

Comment: See @Simoco's answer with the latest edit. You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
With Range("H6:H13")
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**Edit:**

Another solution. Building on Pradeep Kumar's suggestion which deals with preparing your range before you enter the data, Change your code to something like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim aCell As Range

    Range("H6:H13").NumberFormat = "0"

    'This is to cater for any previous values if filled in
    For Each aCell In Range("H6:H13")
        aCell.Formula = aCell.Value
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Entering value for H6
    Range("H6").Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("H6:H13").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a VBA solution, but an ordinary Excel solution.
Do like this

1. Select the column
2. Select Data - Text to columns
3. Quite often the default settings will do and you can click Finish. Otherwise you
   will have to make sure that the result is just a "General" column

A macro doing just this would look something like this:

```
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns
```

There's a lot of parameters to the TextToColumns method, but it should work fine with default values only (i.e. no parameters).

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is this spreadsheet gets sent via email from the VBA code in the userform, therefor I would like to resolve this while still in the userform code.